# how to use sendbird-ui kit with next.js

Tags: next.js, sendbird

I am trying to integrate https://codesandbox.io/s/3-3-customizing-channellist-sg9kx?file=/src/index.css:0-297 in my next.js project.

I am importing dependencies using:

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

const SBProvider = dynamic(
    () => {
        const { SendBirdProvider } = import('sendbird-uikit')
        return SendBirdProvider;
    },
    { ssr: false }
)


const withSendBird = dynamic(
    () => {
        const { withSendBird } = import('sendbird-uikit')
        return withSendBird;
    },
    { ssr: false }
)
```

as provided in the doc

but still getting this
[screen shot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLC4d.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sorry to hear you are having a hard time. The code you are looking for would be something like this.

index.js

```
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

const DynamicAppWithNoSSR = dynamic(() => import("../components/Chat"), {
  ssr: false,
  loading: () => <p>...</p>
});

const App = () => (
   <div>
      <DynamicAppWithNoSSR />
   </div>
);

export default App;
```

Then in Chat.jsx

```
import { App } from "sendbird-uikit";

export default () => (
   <div style={{ height: "95vh" }}>
      <App appId="/*your appID*/" userId="/*your userId*/" />
   </div>
);
```

You can find a working example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-hawking-h3zbs?file=/components/Chat.jsx:0-168). If you have further questions please feel free to join our [Sendbird Community](https://community.sendbird.com/). :)

Comment: Could you provide the above example with typescript ?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'

const DynamicUIKit = dynamic(() => import("sendbird-uikit"))

export default function Home() {
  return (
      <div>
        <DynamicUIKit appId="YOUR-APP-ID" userId="test1" />
      </div>
  )
}
```

You need to import the CSS (see below)

If you start by creating an application from here:
https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/create-nextjs-app

Make sure it works. Then install the UIKit:

```
npm install sendbird-uikit --save
```

In your index.js

```
import { App as SendBirdApp } from "sendbird-uikit";
export default function Home() {
  return (
      <div>
        <SendBirdApp appId="YOUR-APP-ID" userId="ANY-USER-ID" />
      </div>
  )
}
```

You will have to create an _app.js in order to include this CSS:

```
import "sendbird-uikit/dist/index.css";
```

[documentation](https://docs.sendbird.com/javascript/ui_kit_getting_started)